# How to count input lines?

Tags: c++

I need to count lines in my input file, but my code doesn't work how it should:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    unsigned int number, daliklis;
    unsigned long long factorial = 1;

    int lines = 0;
    std::string str;

    std::ifstream input("ardalo.in");
    std::ofstream output("ardalo.out");

    while(std::getline(input, str)) lines++;
    if(lines > 100) {
        cout << "Too many lines.";
        return 0;
    }

    while(input >> number >> daliklis) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++) factorial *= i;
        if(number * daliklis == factorial) output << "YES" << endl;
        else output << "NO" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my input file:

```
5 24
5 16
10000 65537
```

The problem is that when I use getline(input, str), it always makes my output empty. Without using a string the code works fine. What is the problem here?

Comment: Your code first reads all the lines in the file. Then it tries to read more, but that fails because you can't read more than all of it.

Comment: Your second loop will never execute because by the time you get there youve already reached the end of the file using your first loop, you need to reset the "cursor" (i forget the official term for it) to the beginning of the file before the second loop. In short the reason that your first loop stops looping is the same reason your second loop never actually does anything.

Comment: I advise you to get an IDE with a debugger. If you do, you probably won't need to ask questions like this anymore, as you can answer them yourself, saving time & making you feel good :-) The debugger is your best friend

Comment: Also, number and dalkilis are undefined

Comment: @PatrickSturm theyre declared in the first line of main and theyre not read before being written to. Not sure what you mean by "undefined"

Comment: The value of the variables are used but the value is never set, resulting in undefined behaviour. Sorry for my misrepresentation, I see it could be misconstrued now.

Comment: @PatrickSturm `input >> number >> daliklis` and this does not set the value?

Comment: Is that not a simple bit shift? My understanding is it does not assign?

Comment: @PatrickSturm >> is overloaded for streams, it is a read operation. [please consult documentation for more details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Comment: Had a brain fart, my bad